# How to add Teleport to Unattended-upgrades?

Tags: linux, debian, teleport, unattended-upgrade

I would like to use unattended upgrade for [Teleport](https://goteleport.com/integrations/) for Debian 11

I installed and configured UA. Im unsure if i did this correctly of what method is recommended for 3rd party repos.
I referred to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/651918/unattended-upgradeorigins-pattern-for-repository-without-origin-label-etc). I made sure to add the teleport repo to apt list along with all the necessary keys.

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades-teleport

Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
"site=apt.releases.teleport.dev";
};
```

running `unattended-upgrades -d`

```
Checking if system is running on battery is skipped. Please install powermgmt-base package to check power status and skip installing updates when 
the system is running on battery.                                                                                                                 
Starting unattended upgrades script                                                                                                               
Allowed origins are: origin=Debian,codename=bullseye,label=Debian, origin=Debian,codename=bullseye,label=Debian-Security, origin=Debian,codename=b
ullseye-security,label=Debian-Security, site=apt.releases.teleport.dev
...
Checking: teleport ([<Origin component:'main' archive:'' origin:'teleport' label:'teleport' site:'deb.releases.teleport.dev' isTrusted:True>])
adjusting candidate version: teleport=12.4.6
pkgs that look like they should be upgraded: 
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                        
fetch.run() result: 0
Packages blacklist due to conffile prompts: []
No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
Package teleport has a higher version available, checking if it is from an allowed origin and is not pinned down.
Extracting content from /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log since 2023-06-08 18:32:02
```

logs do not provide anything useful

```
cat /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades-dpkg.log

Log started: 2023-06-06  15:52:25
(Reading database ... 136395 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.10.0-20-amd64 (5.10.158-2) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-20-amd64
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-23-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-23-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-21-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-21-amd64
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
done
Log ended: 2023-06-06  15:52:29
```

It does notice a higher teleport package but doesn't upgrade it.